# Apache-PHP not working properly after Django-python installation

Tags: php, django, apache, ubuntu

I want to install `Django Framework` on my Ubuntu(12.04)laptop, already running a `Apache-Php-MySQL` environment.

I followed this tutorial:http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/

I stopped at mod_WSGI installation to check if my old php project would not be affected from new apache config...well they are!
When I try to run them browser not show sites but makes me download the file(ex index.php) of project and show nothing!

What is going on here??

Comment: have you checked apache is running on port 80 ? or possible from that tutorial you have reconfig or reinstall apache ?

Comment: Ok i fixed! here what i've done:

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart